# Get numpy for specific python interpreter (conda / pip)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, conda, miniconda

I need to get numpy for the python27 interpreter that ships with a software we use (Nuke). I would like to avoid installing pip as the interpreter should remain as vanilla as possible. (It does come with ensure pip but `C:\Program Files\Nuke10.5v8>python.exe -m ensurepip` results in the following: No module named ensurepip )

Unfortunatly downloading a seperate python of the same version as the software's interpreter does not work, as pip isn't installed in python 2.7.3 by default and the get-pip.py will result in the known ssl error crap.

I tried a miniconda install with a python 2.7.3 env as well, in order to simply install numpy via conda and copy it, but for some reason the python 2.7.3 from conda is compiled with MSC v. 1500 and the interpreter of the software is compiled with MSC v. 1600.
EDIT: See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/building-conda-packages.html they chose to go with vs2008 python 2.7 instead of vs2010 which I need.

I do not know how to go from here :)

Comment: Have you tried [compiling NumPy from source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/INSTALL.rst.txt)?